# How to delete a given node from a linked list using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to learn linked list in Using python,

Could someone please guide me how to delete a particular give node from a linked list?

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                           

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

def print_list(node):
    while node:
        print node,
        node = node.next
    print

def delete_node(node, node_to_remove):
    if first_node == None:
        return
    pass

# way of creating linked list
def create_linked_list1(n):
    linked_list = Node(1)
    head = linked_list
    for i in range(1, n):
        head.next = Node(i)
        head = head.next
    return linked_list

node1 = create_linked_list1(10)

print_list(node1)
```

Comment: Please show us your linked list implementation. We can't show a `delete` function that works with your implementation unless we know how you implemented it.

Comment: Updated, please verify it and kindly let me know how to delete a given node

Comment: Are you trying to delete by identity, by value, or by index?

Comment: i should say by index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution is this:

```
def delete_by_index(node, index):
    for _ in range(index):
        prev_node, node = node, node.next
    prev_node.next = node.next
```

However, this won't be able to delete the first node. In order to do that, you need to make it return the new list head, which will normally be the old list head, but will instead be the old second node in the case where you deleted the head. So:

```
def delete_by_index(node, index):
    if not index:
        return node.next
    head = node
    for _ in range(index):
        prev_node, node = node, node.next
    prev_node.next = node.next
    return head
```

It should be obvious how to simplify this, and you should do so.

Another option is to factor out the "searching" and "deleting" parts. Write an `nth` function (this should be easy), then you can do this:

```
def delete_by_index(node, index):
    if not index:
        return node.next
    prev_node = nth(node, index-1)
    prev_node.next = prev_node.next.next
    return node
```

If you know about recursive functions, you might also want to figure out how to write either `delete_by_index` or `nth` recursively (it's one of the easiest recursive functions to write).

You may also want to trap the error caused by deleting, say, the 15th node of a 10-node list and make it something nicer. Figure out what error you *would* get in that case (or, if you can't figure it out, just run it and see), then `try`/`except` that, and raise an `IndexError` instead.

While you're at it, you may want to add a `delete_by_data(node, data)` function and maybe a `delete_by_identity(node, child_node)` for further practice.

Comment: Thank you, Reading your answer,

Comment: I think you should write down the `nth` function would be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following **singly linked list** with a pointer, `head`, to the first node

`head ⇢ n0 → n1 →  … → n i - 1 → n i → n i + 1 → … → n N-1 → None`

```
def delete(i):
    if i == 0:                      # there is no prev node, increment head
        head = head.next
    else:
        prev = get_node(i-1)        # find prev node, node[i-1]
        prev.next = prev.next.next  # remove node i
```

Because this is a singly linked list `get_node(i-1)` will have to start at `head` and increment `i-1` times to find the node.

**NOTE:** If this was a doubly linked list, given `node[i]` you can find `node[i-1]` using `node[i].prev`.

Comment: Anyway, this doesn't cover the case of removing node 0. In a sentinel-less linked list implementation, that always complicates things.

Comment: you should clarify `get_node ` method. this is not intact answer

Answer (score 0):

v-> w-> x->y> z and if we want to delete x so that new Linked List is v -> w-> y-> z and we have access to only x

## position of the next node to x i.e. position of the Node Y

next_node = x.next

## swapping the Y to X and then deleting Y `x.data = next_node.data

x.next = next_data.next

Answer (score 0):

Deletion of a node using python in single linked list.

def delete(self,data):

```
    if self.head.data==data:

        temp=self.head.next
        del self.head
        self.head=temp

    else:


      p=self.head
      while p.next.data!=data:
          p=p.next

      temp=p.next.next
      del p.next
      p.next=temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete by value:

```
def delete(head, val):

     if head is None:
       return None


     prev = head
     temp = head.next

     while temp is not None:

         if temp.val == val:
             prev.next = temp.next
             return val

         else:
             prev = temp
             temp = temp.next

     return None
```